# Large monitor Chrome vs IE - Font size so different?

Tags: html, css, fonts, cross-browser, font-size

I have a website with a full size background and some font in the middle of the page as title with a font size of 50px.  On my 27 inch monitor it looks great in Chrome, but way too small in proportion on my IE 11 and Edge browsers.  Both browsers were factory reset and displaying at 100%. Changing zoom on IE fixes issue, but don't want users to have to adjust.

What might be some reasons to explain this?

[image: Chrome]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Probably unrelated but should it not be `"arial, verdana"` (comma)

Comment: Also, try and set the font size in either `rem`'s or `em`'s

Comment: sorry, rem's or em's?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?